# RegionPlot looks wrong

Tags: plotting, regions

I have the following simple RegionPlot of a RegionUnion:

```
RegionPlot[RegionUnion[
  Rectangle[{-0.125, -0.125}, {0.125, 0.125}],  
  Rectangle[{0.126, -0.05}, {0.425, 0.05}]
], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

This looks all good, but when I change the 0.126 to 0.125 to merge the two rectangles the union drops two corners of the region:

[image]

What is going wrong here and how can I display the correct region? Strangely enough with different numeric values it seems to work.

Comment: What version of _Mathematica_ are you running? I got my results with V10.2 running on OS X 10.10.2

Comment: I get what the OP has shown with V10.0 in Windows 10 (64-bit)

Comment: Strange, I get what m_goldberg has on versions 10.0.2, 10.1 and 10.2 (Win 8.1 64 bit).

Comment: @Hubble07 What is your $ReleaseNumber?

Comment: `$ReleaseNumber` is 0

Comment: Just to clarify: I get the plot as shown by the OP with
 `RegionPlot[
 RegionUnion[Rectangle[{-0.125, -0.125}, {0.125, 0.125}], 
  Rectangle[{0.125, -0.05}, {0.425, 0.05}]], AspectRatio -> Automatic]`

Comment: My $ReleaseNumber is 1. Version number is 10.0.1.0. Platform is Linux x86 (64-bit)

Comment: It looks like an issue of 10.0.0 and 10.0.1 then. You should be able to upgrade 1o 10.0.2 for free.

Comment: It is important to always upgrade to the latest bugfix release you have access to. If you have 10.0.0, you can upgrade to at least 10.0.2, possibly also to 10.2.0 depending on your license.  10.0.0 has many bugs, which are the source of lots of questions by people who still haven't installed the bugfix release after more than a year ...

Comment: I have a corporate installation so it is hard to upgrade but I will contact my sysadmin!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but a comment in which I need to show an image.

I don't see any problem with your code. When I evaluate

```
RegionPlot[
  RegionUnion[
    Rectangle[{-0.125, -0.125}, {0.125, 0.125}], 
    Rectangle[{0.125, -0.05}, {0.425, 0.05}]],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

I get

[image: region]

which is exactly what I expect. Are you getting something different? Or, if you getting the same image, why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: Added an image showing how it looks for me

Comment: I'm on 10.2 and duplicated m_goldberg's result.

Comment: I get (almost) your result. That "(almost)" is because the OP has 0.126 in the second rectangle instead of the 0.125 you used.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: The image I show is when using 0.125. With 0.126 it looks ok, but the rectangles are not joined (which is not what I want).